# how to make more operation in <output> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, output

I have coded for output tag, but I could not get actual output for the code.

Code is as

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function myscript()
{
    z.value=parseInt(a.value)+parseInt(b.value);
    c.value=parseInt(a.value)-parseInt(b.value);
    d.value=parseInt(a.value)*parseInt(b.value);
    e.value=parseInt(a.value)/parseInt(b.value);

}
</script>
<form oninput="myScript()">
<input type="range" id="a">
<input type="range" id="b">
<input type="submit"><br/>

Addition<output name="z" for="a b"></output><br/>
Substraction<output name="c" for="a b"></output><br/>
Multiplication<output name="d" for="a b"></output><br/>
Division<output name="e" for="a b"></output>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What is your question? What have you tried?

Comment: to get output with output tag as using scripting. I would return values for a and b variables as operations on them

Comment: Huh.  I had no idea that `<output>` and `oninput` [actually exist](http://html5doctor.com/the-output-element/).

Comment: yap.... its elements of new html version.... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a variety of problems.  I don't think you want to use `oninput`, and  Using `z.value` etc. probably won't work, but is also very shaky.  Try something like:

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var a = +document.getElementById('a').value,
        b = +document.getElementById('b').value;

    document.querySelector('[name="z"]').textContent = a + b;
    //etc.
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/S5XN6/